# dynamic allocation and value of the class member

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

Why does value `k` change, after the second call of `check(base)`?

```
class Base{
public:
    int k=0;
    virtual void print(){
        cout<< k<<endl;
    }
};

Base* check(Base* p){
   Base* t = new Base;
   t->k = 4;
   delete p;
   return t;
}

int main(){
    Base* base = new Base;
    cout<< check(base)->k; // first call, print 4
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<base->k;// print 0
    check(base); // second call
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<< base->k; // print 4
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Ouput:

```
4
0
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing memory pointed by `ptr` after `delete ptr` is [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

My guess in your case is that after you invoke `delete p` (a.k.a. `base`),
`Base* t = new Base` allocates memory where `base` used to point at.